# Empty space at the end of UL list

Tags: javascript, html

http://www.sikni8.com/nas/testfooter.htm

I didnt quite format it for being online yet but what i dnt understand is which is the UL list taking up the emtpty space at the end? How do i fix it so i can center the LI in the DIV labeled headerC?

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: What empty space? The ul is the full width of headerC.

Comment: but i want it to b centered in the middle of headerC

Comment: You mean like gargantaun demonstrated in his answer over 20 minutes ago?

Comment: yes but i think he stepped out but i am not sure what he did... i want it just like his image :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're floating the li's left, so you'll never be able to centre them. Try this

```
li { display: inline-block; }
```

Which gives you this

[image]

you should note though, that inline-block has some pretty poor browser support so it should always be defined like this

```
li
{
    /* for older versions of FF */
    display: -moz-inline-stack;

    /* for modern broswers */
    display:inline-block;

    /* for IE */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;

}
```

Comment: then you need to edit your question and explain the problem better, because I just tried it, and it does work. What you asked was "How do i fix it so i can center the LI in the DIV labeled headerC?"

Comment: hey u got it to WORK!!! thats exactly wat im trying to do... but how come i used the code and FF didnt make the changes for me? THANX SO MUCH

Comment: make sure you define 'inline-block' how I demonstrated in the second part of the answer.

Comment: wud it b possible to send me the HTML file... so i can see it myself? Thanx... i know i shud add it to my CSS what shud i delete? nevermind i got it!!! :) THANX... i added and deleted the float LEFT...

Comment: Also... when i load up the site on my android phone the gray highlight is out of place.. after i put my finger on another link it gets back in place... anyone know how to fix it? thanx

Answer (score 0):

Give you four lis the style `width: 25%;` if you want them to have even spacing, but take up the whole ul.

Comment: no pretty much wat i wud like to do is get rid of the empty spacing so i can center the UL... i want it to center between the two black border on each side... is it clear or am i confusing ppl more?

Comment: @Sikni8 I get it. If you remove the width from `bgv` and `headerC`, and then add the style `display: inline-block;` to both of those elements and to your `ul` you should get what you want, but you will need to change the way you do that backround image to to make it look nice. I'm just going out the door, so maybe someone else can help you with that.

Comment: Also... when i load up the site on my android phone the gray highlight is out of place.. after i put my finger on another link it gets back in place... anyone know how to fix it? thanx

Comment: PaulPRO i did a different method which also worked but thank you!